# Can't get onclick on a button to be accepted

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I currently have a link in the below form:

```
<a href="javascript:changeNumbers('Numbers', '@Url.Action("ChangeNumbers")')">Change</a>
```

In order to fit the look of the site in which I'm adding this link, I want to change it to a button input, as so:

```
<input type="button" value="Change" onclick="changeNumbers('Numbers', '@Url.Action("ChangeNumbers")')" />
```

However, I'm running into a snag with this second form:  the single quotes around `@Url.Action("ChangeNumbers")` are being flagged as `Unterminated string constant`.  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing incorrectly and how to fix it?

**EDIT**

It didn't occur to me to just try the page - it looks like the second form works.  So now my question is - why is Visual Studio flagging this as incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not doing anything "incorrectly" per se, it's just that Razor isn't perfect, and things like quotes within quotes tend to cause it to freak.

One quick fix would be to store the URL in a variable and then use the variable:

```
@{ var url = Url.Action("ChangeNumbers"); }
<input type="button" value="Change" onclick="changeNumbers('Numbers', '@url')" />
```

However, an even better fix is to not use the `onclick` attribute at all. Put this where it belongs: in JS.

```
<script>
    $('#myButton').on('click', function () {
        changeNumbers('Numbers', '@Url.Action("ChangeNumbers")');
    });
</script>
```

*Used jQuery above, since it's included in MVC by default*

Comment: The first one doesn't change the warning I receive - so it doesn't appear to be the quotes.  The second one resolves it.  I will say, though - and this will make it obvious that I'm not a javascript developer - I don't like separating the events away from the tags because then you have to look in more places to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Separation of concerns is more important than not having to scroll down the page a little or open another file. MVC itself separates pieces of functionality into self-contained units. You wouldn't argue that we should go back to circa 1999 PHP-style code-and-HTML mish-mash because then "everything is in one place", would you?

Comment: No, I wouldn't.  However, even with MVC, you can typically know where data is coming from or going to.  But I accept your premise that the right thing to do is to separate it out.

Comment: A nice compromise might be using something like Knockout JS. The Javascript remains separate and contained, but you can still specify the behavior on the element with something like their `click` data binding.

Comment: Taking a quick look, that looks like a clean way to accomplish both needs.  Thanks!

Comment: There's a nuget package for it, as well. It's pretty much an official unofficial part of MVC now, like jQuery. You can use whatever you like, but most people end up using jQuery and Knockout

Comment: knockout-2.1.0.js gets included by default in my MVC 4 projects.  I just haven't started using it yet.  Sounds like it's time.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that to make Visual Studio happy in this scenario, the easiest thing to do is simply change the `<input />` element to a `<button></button>` element and the error will resolve itself:

```
<button type="button" onclick="changeNumbers('Numbers', '@Url.Action("ChangeNumbers")')">Change</button>
```

Otherwise, to continue using an `<input />` the markup will need to be changed to the following:

```
<input type="button" value="Change" onclick="@("changeNumbers('Numbers', '" + Url.Action("ChangeNumbers") + "')")" />
```