# HTML onclick JavaScript function call always highlighted red Razor View/C#

Tags: javascript, c#, html, razor

Occasionally  with `<button>` or `<a>` elements when a JavaScript function is passed to the `onclick` or similar event, the end of the function is highlighted red, still works fine, but I find it really distracting seeing red lines on the code map for no reason.

```
<button onclick="MyApp.SaveRate(this);"></button>
<button onclick="MyApp.SaveRate(this)"></button>

<a onclick="MyApp.SaveRate(this);"></a>
<a onclick="MyApp.SaveRate(this)"></a>
```

It's highlighted in all cases from above, on hover it says *Unterminated string constant*

Is there a way of stopping this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't get onclick on a button to be accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15097027/cant-get-onclick-on-a-button-to-be-accepted)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can resolve it by deleting the cache files located in:

```
C:\Users\your.name.here\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache
```

Restart Visual Studio.

The files will be recreated when you next launch Visual Studio, and they should now be error-free.